Why is my PID controlled state space model always unstable?
My matrix A is a 6x6 matrix and my matrix B is a 6x1 matrix. I tried several different gains and no gain ever works.
The setpoint is a certain position where my system should stabilize.
class PIDController:
    def __init__(self, Kc, Ti, Td, setpoint, A, B, C, D):

        #initializing, for example:

    def compute(self, current_value, current_time):
        error = self.setpoint - current_value[0]  
        
        delta_time = current_time - self.prev_time
        self.prev_time = current_time
        
        # Proportional term
        proportional = self.Kc * error
        self.proportional_values.append(proportional)  
        
        # Integral term
        self.integral += error * delta_time
        self.integral_values.append(self.integral)  # Store integral term
        
        # Derivative term
        self.derivative = (error - self.prev_error) / delta_time
        self.derivative_values.append(self.derivative)  
    
        self.prev_error = error
        
        
        pid_output = proportional + self.Kc/self.Ti * self.integral + self.Kc * self.Td * self.derivative
        
       
        # State-space model simulation
        # x_next is most important. output is just a chosen var from via the C matrix
        x_next = np.dot(self.A, current_value) + self.B * pid_output
        output = np.dot(self.C, current_value) + self.D * pid_output
        
        self.r_values.append(current_value[0])
        self.error_values.append(error)
    
        return output, x_next

I tried adjusting gains ranging from 0.001 - 1000. My system will oscillate for around 6-7 iterations and will then go to infinity very quickly.

Debug the code and log the values for each iteration. Then compare them to the expected values

It's hard to tell or test your function without any knowledge about the system you are trying to control. Maybe you can elaborate more on this for the others to clarify things?

tl;dr
Not every linear timeinvariant system can be stabilized by a pid controller.
An example
Consider a simpler 3 dimensional system given by:
A = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
B = [[0], [0], [1]]
C = [1, 0, 0]
D = [0]

In control theory you often work with so called transfer functions to do some math on your system. This is basically the Laplace transformation of the impulse response of the system. In this particular example you would have the transfer function G(s) = 1/s³ (where s is a complex number). Adding a controller C to the system, you would end up with

GC/(1 + GC)

A PID controller has the transfer function C(s) = Kp + Kd * s + Ki * 1/s. If we insert both G(s) and C(s) in the term above, we end up having

(..some nominator term..)/(s³ + Kd * s + Kp + Ki * 1/s)

In simple words, a system is known to be stable, if all the roots of the denominator-polynomial have negative real parts. Unfortunately, there are no such Kd, Kp and Ki, such that all solutions of the equation

s³ + Kd * s + Kp + Ki * 1/s = 0

have negative real parts. What you may want in this example is an x²-term. In "reality" this might be done with a second order derivative in your pid controller (which then basically would be a pidd² controller), or by cascading multiple pid controllers.
As I mentioned in my comment, it is crutial in control theory to know the details on a system. You cannot expect a pid controller to stabilize all systems.
